# WinBioEnrollBegin gives "DuplicateTemplate" error when try to begin fingerprint enrollment

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi, biometrics

I have a Windows service runs under LocalSystem account. Service can identify fingerprint correctly. My problem is when i start enrollment it gives "DuplicateTemplate" error despite i delete template before starting enrollment.

**I open session with below code;**

```
public void OpenBiometricSession()
{
    session = WinBio32.OpenSession(WinBioBiometricType.Fingerprint, WinBioPoolType.System, WinBioSessionFlag.Raw, null, WinBioDatabaseId.Default);

    WinBio32.WinBioAcquireFocus();
}
```

**I delete user template by below code before i call AddEnrollment;**

```
public void DeleteUserTemplate(SecurityIdentifier userSid)
{
    var cloneIdentity = new WinBioIdentity(userSid);

    if (cloneIdentity != null && cloneIdentity.AccountSid != null)
    {
        WinBio32.DeleteTemplate(session, unitId, cloneIdentity, 
WinBioBiometricSubType.Any);
    }
}
```

**I start enrollment with below code;**

```
private bool AddEnrollment()
{
    var ccc = WinBio32.EnrollBegin(session, WinBioBiometricSubType.LhIndexFinger, 
    unitId);

    var code = WinBioErrorCode.MoreData;

    for (var swipes = 1; code != WinBioErrorCode.Ok; swipes++)
    {
        code = WinBio32.EnrollCapture(session, out var rejectDetail);

        switch (code)
        {
            case WinBioErrorCode.MoreData:
            case WinBioErrorCode.BadCapture:
               {
                   enrollmentActionCallback?.Invoke($"Parmağınızı kaldırın ve tekrar 
yerleştirin / {swipes}");

                break;
            }
        case WinBioErrorCode.Ok:
            {
                enrollmentActionCallback?.Invoke($"Parmak izi tanımlama başarılı");

                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                enrollmentActionCallback?.Invoke("Bilinmeyen bir hata oluştu");

                WinBio32.EnrollDiscard(session);

                return false;
            }
    }
}

WinBio32.EnrollCommit(session, out identity);

return true;
}
```

**Below code always gives "DuplicateTemplate" error despite i delete template before;**

```
var ccc = WinBio32.EnrollBegin(session, WinBioBiometricSubType.LhIndexFinger, 
unitId);
```

When I test same code in a Form application, it succeeds. Only fails when runs in Windows Service

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: I think i understand the problem, when I enroll this for the first time, it saves my fingerprint to LocalSystem SID. After enrollment, if I identify my fingerprint, it gives LocalSystem SID. How can i correct this?

Comment: I noticed that *WINBIO_FLAG_DEFAULT The biometric units operate in the manner specified during installation. You must use this value when the PoolType parameter is WINBIO_POOL_SYSTEM*.

Comment: Should i open private database then?

Comment: `DatabaseId` *If the PoolType parameter is WINBIO_POOL_PRIVATE, you must specify the GUID of an installed database. If the PoolType parameter is not WINBIO_POOL_PRIVATE, you can specify one of the following common values*. Have you tried the WINBIO_POOL_PRIVATE pool type?

Comment: No i havent try? I will check and post result here. Thanks.